# How can I link to a specific page on a facebook iframe app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-iframe

i created an iframe application and embedded this application in a page. Is it possible to create a link to a specific page in the iframe application?

This is the link to the application:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGENAME/123456?sk=app_123456

I need to put some GET parameters to the url like "item_id".

How can i do that?

greetings

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can add specific GET parameters in the URL for the page tab for the application. Facebook doesn't pass variables like that to your application.
What you can do, is change the application settings in facebook and change the canvas tab URL and add a fixed get parameter there.

Comment: i found a soulution: you can send in the signed_request some "app_data" as JSON.

"A JSON string containing the content of a query string parameter also called app_data. Usually specified when the application built the link to pass some data to itself. Only available if your app is an iframe loaded in a Page tab."

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: More information about the app_data method here - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462